# Remove Textbox from document using Word JS Api

Tags: office-js, office-addins, cpu-word

I am trying to remove Textboxes from a document and replace them with their text.
I know that Word JS API does nor provide a straightforward method to handle textboxes.
So I am trying to do it by either updating the document's OOXML or by deleting the selected range and inserting the piece of text.

Although I am able to select Shapes, pictures, tables and perform this action, I fail once it comes to Textboxes or once the selected object includes a piece of text. e.g. A shape or a Wordart in which we have added some text. This is the code I am using once I delete the range

```
Word.run(function (context) {

        let rng = context.document.getSelection();

        return context.sync().then(function () {
            rng.delete();

            return context.sync().then(function () {

                rng.insertText("Foo - Bar", Word.InsertLocation.replace);

                return context.sync().then(function () {
                    console.log('done');
                });

            });
        });
    })
```

The result I am getting is that only the text is replaced but it's container (the textbox) remains.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally took the following workaround. It works nicely and fast in both Windows & macOs

1. Get OOXML of the document's body
2. Parse OOXL.value &  Generate an xmlDocument (xmlDoc)
3. Detect existing Textboxes & Shapes that contain text:  getElementsByTagName("wps:wsp")
4. Extract text from (3)
5. Generate a simple xml  TextElement with text extracted
6. Replace (3) with (5)
7. Serialize to xmlString  the updated xmlDoc and get the updated OOXML.value
8. Insert updated OOXML.value to document replacing the existing one

   Word.run(function (context) {

   ```
        //Select document body and extract OOXML 
        const body = context.document.body;
        const ooxml = body.getOoxml();

        return context.sync().then(function () {

            //Initialize DOM Parser
            const parser = new DOMParser();
            const xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(ooxml.value, "text/xml");

            //Get all runs
            const rows = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("w:r");
            for (let j = 0; j < rows.length; j++) {
                const row = rows[j];
                const rowHasTextBox = row.getElementsByTagName("wps:txbx").length > 0;
                //If no textbox, shape, wordart exists skip current run
                if (!rowHasTextBox) continue;

                //Select textbox, shape, wordart and get paragraphs
                const textboxContainer = row.getElementsByTagName("wps:txbx")[0];
                const paragraphs = textboxContainer.getElementsByTagName("w:p");

                // Create a new run which will replace the existing run
                const newRow = xmlDoc.createElement("w:r");
                const breakLine = xmlDoc.createElement("w:br");
                //Append breakline and "{{"
                newRow.appendChild(breakLine);
                newRow.appendChild(startRow);

                for (let p = 0; p < paragraphs.length; p++) {
                    //Check whether paragrapj has text
                    const paragraphHasText = paragraphs[p].getElementsByTagName("w:t").length > 0;
                    if (!paragraphHasText) continue;
                    //Extract text
                    let textExtracted = "";
                    const textBoxTexts = paragraphs[p].getElementsByTagName("w:t");
                    for (let k = 0; k < textBoxTexts.length; k++) {
                        const textBoxText = textBoxTexts[k].innerHTML;
                        textExtracted = textExtracted + textBoxText;
                        textExtracted = textExtracted + " ";
                    }
                     // Create a temp run which will hold the etxtracted text
                    const tempRow = xmlDoc.createElement("w:r");
                    const newText = xmlDoc.createElement('w:t');
                    newText.setAttribute("xml:space", "preserve");
                    newText.innerHTML = textExtracted;
                    textExtracted = "";
                    tempRow.appendChild(newText);
                    newRow.appendChild(tempRow);
                    const breakLine = xmlDoc.createElement("w:br");
                    newRow.appendChild(breakLine);
                }


                //Replace existing run with the new one
                row.replaceWith(newRow);
            }
            //Serialize dom , clear body and replace OOXML
            const serializedXML = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xmlDoc.documentElement);
            body.clear();
            return context.sync().then(function () {
                body.insertOoxml(serializedXML, Word.InsertLocation.replace);
                console.log('done');
            });
        });
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log('Error: ', error);
        resolve(false);
    });
   ```